# Error in python finding coolness of the number

Tags: python

coolness of the number is defined as the number of "101"s occuring in its binary representation. If the number binary representation  has "101" then it's coolness is 1
A number is defined as very cool if it's coolness is greater than or equal to  k

input : 21 2 output: 1

but i'm getting

output:2 instead of 1

```
 def v(j):
       res=''
        c=0
      while j>0:
        res=res+str(j%2)
        j=j//2
        for i in range(2,len(res)):
            if res[i]+res[i-1]+res[i-2]=="101":
                c+=1
    return c>=k
n,k=map(int,input().split())
r=0
for i in range(2,n+1):
    if v(i):
        r=r+1
print(r)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Indentation of for loop was wrong i.e. it's within while loop.so assigning proper indentation will resolve the issue.

```
while j>0:
    res=res+str(j%2)
    j=j//2
for i in range(2,len(res)):
    if res[i]+res[i-1]+res[i-2]=="101":
        c+=1
return c>=k
```

Comment: I don't consider code without an explanation to be very helpful unless OP just wants their homework done for them. We're suuposed to be here to eduacate people as well.

Comment: This code is unnecessarily convoluted, the variable names are opaque, and it doesn't use good programming practices, such as slicing syntax.

Comment: How is this even different from the original code?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to calculate the "coolness" is to use built-in functions rather than to invent yours. Function `bin(x)` converts an integer number to a string with its binary representation. Method `str.count()` counts the substrings.

```
bin(21).count('101')
# 1
```

Comment: May want to clarify whether `21` (`0b10101`) should give one or two occurrences. It's one if no overlaps allowed, two otherwise. ... Never mind, question seems to be clear it should be non-verlapping.